# Visualization of dynamic data on top of OpenStreetMap tiles?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, visualisation, dynamic, dynamic-layer

I want to show dynamic data (say .2 sec update) from a postGIS database displayed on top of OpenStreetMap data.

I am very new to GIS so not sure how to go about this.

I am thinking something like:

1. Prerender OSM tiles + serve with GeoServer (or MapServer).
2. Serve the dynamic data separate from GEOServer. This could just be lat long coords.
3. Use OpenLayers in broswer to place the dynamic data on top of the tiles.

Is it possible to do what I am thinking here and if so, does this seem reasonable? 
Would it be better to render everything server side and send back result? Or should I not prerender tiles?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen application based on moving objects that only use GeoServer, GWC cached tiles for the background (in case OSM/Google are not fitting your needs) and periodic WFS queries to fetch the current position of the objects.

If the objects are mostly moving all of the time it's probably going to be efficient enough, if you are instead facing a case in which only a few objects change position (mostly static objects) it would be probably best to reverse the approach and use websockets to push updates to the clients as one particular object moves.